# Copying stuff from Vim running in PuTTY

Tags: vim, mouse, clipboard, copy-paste, putty

I am running Vim 6.3 through [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) and PuTTY Connection Manager. I have the mouse option set (`set mouse = a`). I am able to paste things from the (Windows) clipboard to Vim by <Shift + right clicking>, but selecting text in Vim <left click followed by right click> isn't copying anything to the clipboard. How do I do this?

Note: I can't update Vim to a newer version.

Comment: Isn't it more customary to use `set mouse=a` (without the spaces)?

Comment: Related: *[Copying text outside of Vim with set mouse=a enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608161/copying-text-outside-of-vim-with-set-mouse-a-enabled)*. Includes *"After enabling set mouse=a, text copied inside of Vim will not paste outside of Vim."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select some text with the mouse and then type:
`"*y` to yank the selected text to the clipboard. Then you should be able to use the clipboard content in another application.

If `"*y` is to cumbersome to type, you can put the following in the host .vimrc:

`:noremap y "*y`

Comment: This did not copy the text to clipboard. I don't know where it copied it, but Dunnie's answer should have been accepted based on the current state of Putty.

Comment: had the same issue with MobaXterm on Windows and vim in ssh. For me it worked after adding `ForwardX11Trusted yes` to my `~/.ssh/config` as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/326871/using-clipboard-through-ssh-in-vim) and get `vim-gnome` to add the clipboard feature as explained [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim)

Comment: since on Windows there is no difference between the `*` (copy-on-select) and the `+` (Ctrl+C) register, using the default register with `"y` works. Go into visual mode with `v` and following navigation moves instead of using the mouse for text selection works as well.

Answer (score 70):

Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and then highlight the text you want to copy using the left mouse button. When you release, the highlighted text should be in the Windows clipboard.

Comment: While this works, it isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Instead of copying everything from the beginning to the end of the selection, it copies everything in the box. Is there a way to getting things to the clipboard after I've made the selection?

Comment: Set selection mode to normal in Putty configuration (Window/Selection). I can copy and paste from putty as from any other window app.

Comment: The selection mode is normal, I still get the box. Maybe it is an issue with Putty Connection Manager?

Comment: Not sure. I  use left Mouse to select and Ctlr-C to copy from vim and it works.

Comment: I can only use this to copy what is in the box. Scrolling doesn't work. I'm using MTPutty.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. One thing to note is if you have number lines showing, it might be better to hold down Shift and Alt (windows).

Comment: Hold Alt for block select.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to copy, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste.

Comment: How to copy all lines(include the lines that don't display in the window)? It only can copy the lines that display in the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `mouse=a`.
Put the mouse in command line mode (`:set mouse=c`).

Then you can just select your text to put it in the system clipboard (as with all other PuTTY/[KiTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitty_(terminal_emulator)) commands).

Comment: This is correct, but why is that? I would like the mouse selection to use the visual mode in vim and y to copy to selection to all clipboards.