# How to clear the line number in Vim when copying?

Tags: linux, vim

I copy some code from one part of one file to another part in vim, I find that, there are line numbers in each line and the format is gone, how to set correct format as origin ?

like this:

```
            40         root /opt/release/current/public;
 67             41         passenger_enabled on;
 68              42
```

Comment: What do you mean by format? Vim does not work with formatted text at all.

Comment: sorry, format means spaces and line number

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you have line numbers, I'm quite sure you are not using Vim's yank/put operations (these will *never* copy the linenumbers, foldcolumn, icons etc) because in terms of the edit buffer, they don't exist.

My guess is you are working in a terminal emulator and using the mouse to copy stuff to the clipboard, which possibly selects the 'extraneous' room of the screen (including virtual spaces at the end, line numbers, fold markers etc)

You might have luck setting

```
:se mouse+=a
```

in order to get the behaviour of the mouse like you expect it. Otherwise, do the selection with <kbd>V</kbd>`<movement>...`<kbd>y</kbd> (`y` for `yank`, which corresponds to 'copy')

Then on the destination use <kbd>p</kbd> (put at cursor), or <kbd>P</kbd> (put before cursor)

Let me know if that helped or you need more info

Comment: The yank + paste operation works well within vim but what about pasting to another editor or a remote terminal ?

Comment: Use Ctrl+Shift+Click to select the text should works.

Comment: @nawesita Good hint. That heavily depends on the terminal emulator being used, and only on that. But it might be useful, even when Vim isn't involved

Comment: Have in mind that `:set mouse+=a` will get you to [clipboard problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608161/copying-text-outside-of-vim-with-set-mouse-a-enabled).

Comment: how to toggle :se mouse+=a ?

Comment: @Mahdimehrabi have you tried `:se mouse-=a`? (I misrembered the bit about toggling, see `:help :set^=`)

Comment: The following answer provides a working solution compatible with `set mouse+=a`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608206/6108874 Now I can use `Ctrl-C` to copy visual selection to system clipboard - even use the mouse to make the selection :)

Answer (score 44):

In case anyone wants a quicker way (on Linux anyways), I have noticed in vim you can hold down ctrl and drag over the region you want to copy and you'll avoid the line numbers and select the part you want.

**Steps**:

1. ctrl and drag over area
2. release ctrl
3. copy (either keyboard shortcut or right click)

Comment: vim on what? When I hold ctrl I end up right clicking. Any other key and I still get the line numbers.

Comment: Erm, are you letting go of ctrl before you right click?? Also, I was using Linux.

Comment: I like this answer. On Mac, you hold option(alt) instead of ctrl. The highlighted region will be similar to visual selection in lowercase `v` mode.

Comment: Awesome! I have got used to typing ```:se nonu``` too. Which another guy gave as an answer.

Comment: That's Amazing!

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I am using moba Xterm on windows

Comment: This worked, but the only problem is - if a long line wraps around the next line, this method copies it as two lines instead of one.

Comment: this selects a rectangular region for me

Answer (score 43):

In normal mode, type `:se nonu`

This is the easiest way to remove the line numbers and you will be able to copy the text without the line numbers.

Comment: Esc Mode? Now there's a Vim mode I haven't previously explored (I think you may mean 'Ex' mode, although the suggested command suggests you really start in 'normal' mode)

Comment: he means the "normal mode" . If you are in insert mode (or anyother), press `Esc` to return to normal mode.

Answer (score 27):

A permanent solution for this is to add the below code at the end of your `.vimrc` file located in your home directory.

```
se mouse+=a
```

By adding this you will be able to select only text and not the line numbers as shown in below image:

[image]

---

If you are not getting your `.vimrc` file in your home directory (i faced this problem), type the command `:scriptnames` in vi editor, it will display the location of your `.vimrc` file. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10933797/3603374)

Comment: On Linux Mint too @Ilias Karim.

Comment: indeed, ubuntu too

Comment: This enables mouse mode, is it possible to acquire the copying feature without enabling the mouse mode?

Comment: Can't believe I had to scroll this low to get the actual solution, should be marked

Comment: I have `set mouse+=a` and it still copies line numbers. Better to avoid mouse and create a shortcut for `"+y`.

Answer (score 24):

On Mac: I found out that you can select the desired area with Option+Command and copy paste it to another editor.

Comment: you just made my day!

Comment: I wish this was higher in the answers so that I could have seen it earlier !

Comment: This does not remove trailing spaces.

Answer (score 8):

All the previously entered solution are very good one. However, sometimes your are using vim on a remote server (so you cant copy to your clipboard using `"+y`). Often terminals support copy paste operation.

I use vim to output visual selection to a new shell where I can copy text using terminal feature:

```
:'<,'>w ! bash -c cat
```

Then I can easily copy the output.

Same pattern for pasting in vim:

```
:r ! bash -c cat
```

Then I paste and send EOF to cat using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. This method also avoid reindenting the text you paste (Note: you can disable automatic indentation using `:set pi!`).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the pastetoggle option sometimes set to F11.

As an alternative you could always write the section you want to copy into a temporary file 
(`ma`, goto end line then use `:'a,.w tempfile`) then read it into the second file.

For further investigation you might want to look at the autoindent option.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows VIM GUI: `:set nu` and then hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> while
highlighting the desired text with the mouse. This yanks the line numbers
into the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows using Putty, I have noticed in vim you can hold down ALT and drag over the region you want to copy and you'll avoid the line numbers and select the part you want.

**Steps**:

1. Press and Hold ALT
2. Drag over area
3. Release ALT
4. Copy using CTRL+Shift+C (or right click if that is turned on)

**Variations:**

The specific key may be different based on your specific set up.
If ALT does not work, try the following keys instead:

1. CTRL
2. CTRL+Shift
3. ALT+Shift

**Note:**

If anyone knows of any other key combinations that have worked for them let me know and I will update this answer with them.

Answer (score 0):

I mapped the below command to a key.
It strips the whitespace around the copied line numbers.
It ignores the line text and any blank lines behind.

```
:1,$s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s//\|1,$s/^\s*[0-9]\+\n/\r/<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using `sed` and `pbcopy` to copy the lines to a clipboard, where you can paste to another terminal or apps outside of vim.

`sed -n <line start #>,<line end #>p <file name> | pbcopy`

Answer (score 0):

simplest way just: $ cat "your file"
and then just copy it from your terminal without numbers