# Copying Vim codes to stack overflow

Tags: vim, copying

I am trying to easily copy over codes from vim editor to stackedoverflow or other coding webs.

Vim is easy to yank with highlight+y, but those yanked lines do not get pasted to stackOverflow with Ctrl+V outside of the editor. How can I accomplish the mission?

Most of this websites links such as [Copying text outside of Vim with set mouse=a enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608161/copying-text-outside-of-vim-with-set-mouse-a-enabled) have not worked.

I would think this should be a very straight-forward and easy answer but never found one yet.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: It's Ubuntu16.04 Linux!

Comment: Are you using gvim or the terminal vim? If the latter, are you using a graphical terminal emulator such as gnome-terminal?

Comment: Dup of https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/2312

Comment: It's the vim that pops up when I type vim in standard linux terminal. 

I am not sure if it is gnome-terminal or graphical terminal emulator....

Comment: I saw the thread but could not understand AT ALL. I would sincerely appreciate if someone could give 1-sentence solution for the given problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend using the [vim-highlightedyank plugin](https://github.com/machakann/vim-highlightedyank) because it highlights the every time you copy something.

The copy can be achieved by:

```
"+yip ................ (copy current paragraph to the clipboard)
"+ ................... the clipboard
yip .................. yank inner paragraph

:%y+ ................. copy the whole file to the clipboard
```

If you have any selection just type:

```
"+y
```