# vim select buffer to clipboard via putty ssh connection

Tags: vim, putty

I'm trying to wrap my head around this but so far I got no clue how to do it.

I connect to my server via ssh and I was wondering how I could copy lines from visual mode straight to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the register in witch you can copy anything. The list of available registers is available through `:registers`. The clipboard register is usualy `"*`. Therefore if you want to copy anything in this register, just prefix the yank command by the register, ie: `"*y`. The steps would be like :

- Enter visual mode (`Shift-v` for instance`)
- Select your lines (mouvement)
- Type `"*y`

To make the copy work with putty, you'll have to enable X-forwarding, vf [Copy from Putty/Vim visual mode to windows clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741511/copy-from-putty-vim-visual-mode-to-windows-clipboard)